# How to Get Some Data and set into other page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 3 website pages

1) Where My form Saved
2) Results.html
3) an onther page like results.html

When i enter zip code and press enter its show some data which is fetched from Website, i have one more page like results.html and the code is exactly but data is different, But problem is that when i try to show that an other data it again asking about zip code but user already put it on home page, i need that user can put zip code on home page and the zipcode set on all the pages that i need using javascript.

Any thing like this possible.

See the live example
http://innovativeartz.com/Query

Enter Zip : 95110 its shows the data and than you see on right side HOME button just click here its asking the zip code again i need it will put automaticly since user input it on homepage.

Thanks

```
**HTML**   
 <form action="results.html" method="get" >
    Zip Code: <input type="text" name="zipcode" size="10" maxlength="5" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Get Quotes" />
    </form>

**Java Script**

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getQueryStringVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split('=');
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
    return pair[1];}}}

    ni_ad_client = "579660";
    ni_res_id = 2;
    ni_alt_url = "https://www.shmktpl.com/search.asp";
    ni_zc = getQueryStringVariable('zipcode');
    ni_str_state_code = getQueryStringVariable('statecode');
    ni_var1 = "";
    ni_display_width = 650;
    ni_display_height = 1000;
    ni_color_border = "";
    ni_color_bg = "";
    ni_color_link = "";
    ni_color_url = "";
    ni_color_text = "";
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.shmktpl.com/retrieve_listings.asp"></script>

    <noscript><a href="https://www.shmktpl.com/search.asp?src=579660&res=2"><img src="https://www.shmktpl.com/images/nojs/image.asp?src=579660&res=2" border="0"></a></noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Home button on the right is just a simple a-link. I presume that you should append the zipcode to the end of this link's href, using JavaScript.